# Can "edge" and "vertex" be defined in a way that isn't circular?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I haven't been able to find any forum where this question has been asked. To clarify: every definition of vertex I've seen makes reference to edges, and vice versa. Is it possible to define one or both of these terms independently of the other?

Comment: I have never seen "vertex" defined in terms of "edge".  Can you give an example?

Comment: A (simple, undirected) graph is a pair $(V, E)$ with $V$ an arbitrary set and $E$ a set of unordered pairs $\{v, v'\}$ with $v\not= v'$ in $V$.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. A vertex is an element of a set $V$. And an edge is an element of a set $E$. Period.

---

If we *additionally* have an incidence relation $I\subseteq V\times E$ with the properties

- $\forall e\in E\colon \exists v\in V\colon (v,e)\in I$
- $\forall (v,e)\in I\colon \exists! w\in V\setminus\{v\}\colon (w,e)\in I$

(i.e., each edge is incident with exactly two vertices) then the tuple $(V,E,I)$ is a simple undirected graph.

Comment: What is an element, and what is a set?

Comment: @allisonkaas Informally, a [set](https://www.mathwords.com/s/set.htm) is any collection of things at all, and [an element of a set](https://www.mathwords.com/e/element_of_a_set.htm) is just a thing in that collection, often called a "member" of the set. Formally, one might pick a [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) like [zfc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFC) and then sets are things that satisfy those axioms about membership, and their members may [or may not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) be forced to be sets.